# How to enable 'devices' controller support in grub?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, qemu, virt-manager

I am running ubuntu 22.04 with virt-manager installed, when I run `virt-host-manager` I get

```
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : WARN (Enable 'devices' in kernel Kconfig file or mount/enable cgroup controller in your system)
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support                         : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if IOMMU is enabled by kernel                               : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for secure guest support                                    : WARN (Unknown if this platform has Secure Guest support)
   .
   .
   .

   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : FAIL (Enable 'devices' in kernel Kconfig file or mount/enable cgroup controller in your system)
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'freezer' controller support                     : FAIL (Enable 'freezer' in kernel Kconfig file or mount/enable cgroup controller in your system)
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
   LXC: Checking if device /sys/fs/fuse/connections exists                   : PASS
```

How do you enable `'devices' controller support`, what should I add/modify in `/etc/default/grub` to enable it

Answer (score 2):

Basically, just edit `/etc/sysconfig/grub` and change the line that looks like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet intel_iommu=on systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"`. Then run these two commands:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

I recommend making a copy of these three files before any of this just incase you need to restore them for any reason.

> QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support
> : WARN (Enable 'cpuset' in kernel Kconfig file or mount/enable cgroup
> controller in your system) QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices'
> controller support                     : WARN (Enable 'devices' in
> kernel Kconfig file or mount/enable cgroup controller in your system)
> QEMU: Checking for secure guest support
> : WARN (Unknown if this platform has Secure Guest support) LXC:
> Checking for cgroup 'freezer' controller support
> : FAIL (Enable 'freezer' in kernel Kconfig file or mount/enable cgroup
> controller in your system)
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> sudo nvim /etc/sysconfig/grub
> ```
>
> Add `intel_iommu=on` and `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0`
> properties at the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line.
>
> ```
> ## Example row with Fedora 33 BTRFS ##
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet intel_iommu=on systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
> ```
>
> Update grub2 conf
>
> ```
> ## BIOS ##
> sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
>
> ## UEFI ##
> sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
> ```
>
> `reboot`
>
> [image]
>
> > The validation tool will report the following warning message if the server has Intel processors. It is expected because the validation
> > tool does not check Secure Guest on Intel processors:
>
> QEMU: Checking for secure guest support: WARN (Unknown if this
> platform has Secure Guest support)
>
> [Source](https://medium.com/@yping88/use-ubuntu-server-20-04-cloud-image-to-create-a-kvm-virtual-machine-with-fixed-network-properties-62ecae025f6c)
>
> Source code:
>
> - https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2020-May/msg00416.html
> - https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/a2196bc2389c6d87d523f71380615337cce2e7a3/src/qemu/qemu_capabilities.c#L4701
>
> Probably this feature detection for Intel processors is not yet
> implemented as I can see from the source code linked above. I assume
> it is safe to ignore this warning.

[source](https://github.com/dzintars/infra/issues/28#issue-771042619)

Comment: On Ubuntu, I guess you mean this file needs to be edited instead: `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`